# Yii2 - Restricting Pages by IP

Tags: yii2

I want to restrict the Error pages by IP in the development environment.

In the site controller, I tried to add the access rule, but that doesn't seems to work with `error` action like:

```
[
      'actions' => ['error'],
      'allow' => true,
      'roles' => ['?'],
      'ips' => ['my-ip'],
],
```

[image]

Comment: what error are you getting ? is it saying you are not allowed to view this page? and `actions` should have those actions you want to apply this rule to

Comment: Hi Omer it is giving the detailed error page, of course it is the exception on the top of the error page. but it includes all the code of the controller, where I am restricting it to ip.

Comment: and what is that exception ? is the same as i mentioned in my previous comment ? you might have to change the `'roles' => ['?'],` to `'roles' => ['@'],`

Comment: and if i dont get you wrong you are trying to limit the access to the specific pages via `IP` ?

Comment: Yes that is right, but additionally I want that if there is any error on any page of whatever reason that is not visible to all visitors. so basically restricting the error action of yii to specific IP.

Comment: you want the error trace to be shown while still being on a `prod` env , that might not be possible anyhow, you can mail or add log targets but as far as i know you cant show the error trace while still on a `prod` environment , all it will show is that `An internal server error occurred.`

Comment: No I am on development. and I want to show the error trace, but visible only to specific IP, so for others it will be like production environment. Yes for other it will be like you mentioned - all it will show is that An internal server error occurred

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended that you set the access permission of the error page. This will give another prompt message that does not have access to the error page when the user without permission has an error. The prompt is also not friendly.

If your goal is to display different levels of error pages for different ips, you can override the \yii\web\ErrorAction to display different error pages for different privileged users, for example:

```
class MyErrorAction extends \yii\web\ErrorAction {
    public function run()
    {
        if ('ip1' === \Yii::$app->request->userIP) {
            return $this->renderHtml1();
        }

        if ('ip2' === \Yii::$app->request->userIP) {
            return $this->renderHtml2();
        }

        return $this->renderDefaultHtml();
    }
}
```

Then in the project's configuration file, configure the errorHandler's errorAction as your MyErrorAction, for example:

```
[
    'components' => [
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => MyErrorAction::class
        ],
    ],
]
```

Or you can override the \yii\web\ErrorHandle::renderException() method to control the content of the presentation and configure errorHandle in the configuration file as your MyErrorHandler

This answer is translated from Google Translate

Comment: Thanks Luna for your suggestion. Just would like to know, why Yii will show stack-trace when an exception is set in an access-control for a controller/action?

Comment: Yii registers the error and exception handlers for the entire application when the application is initialized, and the exception thrown by the access control is also captured. This will determine how to display the exception information based on your ErrorHandle configuration. There is the following code in \yii\base\Application: public function __construct(...) {...; $this->registerErrorHandler($config);...;}. This answer is translated from Google Translate